# Непонятная проблема с переводом приложения android

Tags: android

У себя в приложении я использую на данный момент три языка: русский, украинский и английский. Есть три файлика со строками, и вроде при изменении языка все переводится нормально, кроме одной строки. Вот все строки нормально меняются, но одна строка ни в какую. Приведу пример: поменяли мы язык на русский, так эта строка ставится на английский, либо наоборот из английской версии видно русский текст. Я уже перепроверил все доки, но не нашел причины такого странного поведения приложения.

Помогите пожалуйста понять причину этого глюка.

P.S. Честно говоря плохо представляю, что именно вам здесь показать, так как все файлы идентичны, проблемы только в одной строке. Но если что-то нужно, то скажите и я докину)

Comment: Думаю причина в том где и как она используется. Скорее всего механизм сохранения состояния восстанавливает её из сейва. P.S. `location` - это про гео-позиционирование.

Comment: Что за строка и каким образом вы её используете в коде?

Comment: эта строка - это заголовок активити